# how to add make curved modal bottom sheet like in this picture? how to add a close button above it? in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

[image: like this]
I want to add a bottom model sheet just like this one,
also let me know how to add that pink close button above it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Stack() and put the button on top of it with a Positioned()

Comment: Already tried With Stack but its not working, I think stack can only works on its parent widget ,that means it can't place a object out side  bottom Sheet

Comment: Does the Stack() wrap all widgets on the screen?